# Getting java OutOfMemoryError when mapping big list of tuples

Tags: scala

My function is simply takes a csv file that was uploaded and have some formatting problems and calling another function to clean it and fix its formatting.

but when I call my cleaning function with a file (as string) that is very big I get the error:

> [ERROR] [24/02/2017] [application-scheduler-1]
>   [ActorSystem(application)] Uncaught error from thread
>   [application-scheduler-1] shutting down JVM since
>   'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled 
>    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

this is where it fails:

```
  def clean(fileStr: String): String = {

    val zippedWithIndex = fileStr.zipWithIndex

    // i need to map it like this for the next stage of my cleaning
    val indexCharMap = zippedWithIndex.map(cur => (cur._2,cur._1)).toMap

    // my string builder
    val builder = new StringBuilder()


...

}
```

it fails in the `zippedWithIndex.map` since the file is very big (the `fileStr.length` is 10948026)

i need it cause im iterating on zippedWithIndex and I need to have the ability to check the char before and after (for example: `indexCharMap.get(chr._2 - 1))`

it just think for like a minute and then throws the exception above.

what would be a better way to solve it?

(except moving to streams, that would be in the second version of this product)

thanks!

So now it works like this:

I need to have a proper csv file, which is:

```
"Header1","Header2","Header3"

"value1","value2","value3"
```

but the file that im getting is getting out of some system that i dont have access to and the formatting is broken, which means i can get a file like this:

```
"Header1","Header2","Header3"

"val"ue1","val"ue2","val"ue"3"
```

its because that in the values im getting can be quotes and the system that takes them out is not doing proper escaping, which should make it look like this:

```
"Header1","Header2","Header3"

"val""ue1","val""ue2","val""ue""3"
```

because csv format works in a way that if you want to have quite inside value you need to put double quotes.

so to fix it im iterating through zippedWithIndex and the logic goes like:

```
 zippedWithIndex.foreach( chr => {

 builder.append(chr._1)

if(!currentlyInsideValue && begginingOfValue(indexCharMap.get(chr._2 - 1)))
        currentlyInsideValue = true

 else if (currentlyInsideValue && endingValue(indexCharMap.get(chr._2 + 1)))
        currentlyInsideValue = false
      else
        builder.append('"')

}
```

Comment: You need to tell us more information about what do you want to do for `indexCharMap`?

Comment: @chengpohi i need it cause im iterating on zippedWithIndex and I need to have the ability to check the char before and after (for example: `indexCharMap.get(chr._2 - 1))`

Comment: val zippedWithIndex = fileStr.zipWithIndex ? Won't this create an index for every char in your input string? Is that what you really want? Ah. Your comment above suggests you do. Ok

Comment: Your data is very large. Please explain whether to clean it up you need to have it all in memory at the same time, or you can examine the file one line at a time, or in large chunks, etc.

Comment: @radumanolescu i need to have it all at once i think since im fixing a broken csv format

Comment: Can you give an example of a "broken" line in the CSV file, and the same line after it's fixed? Can you get your code to work on a small file, then post it all here so we can see what you are doing, and we'll be able to think about scaling your problem up to a large file?

Comment: @radumanolescu added in the end of the question a full explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not need to hold the whole file in memory, just one line of text at a time. Try a program like the one below. Write your own code inside of `cleanOneLine`, to fix the quotes inside one line of text

```
import scala.io.Codec
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.PrintWriter

object CSVCleaner {
  val fileName = "Broken.csv"
  val output = "Fixed.csv"

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    clean(fileName)
  }

  def clean(fileStr: String) {
    val pw = new PrintWriter(output)
    val source = Source.fromFile(fileName)(Codec.ISO8859)
    source.getLines.foreach { line =>
      val clean = cleanOneLine(line)
      pw.print(clean + "\n")
    }
    pw.flush
    pw.close
    source.close
  }

  def cleanOneLine(line: String): String = {
    // your code here
    "put, your, code, here" // ToDo
  }
}
```

Comment: its a good solution, but in my case the csv is as i said not in such good formatting, and I have allot of \n in the middle of a string, and getLines gives  me broken lines...do you have some other solution, maybe one that i can still keep the process on the whole file..?

Comment: It sounds like you cannot guarantee (and by "you" I mean the upstream system) that words do not contain double quotes, or newlines. What can you guarantee? If you could guarantee that "each line of the CSV contains the same N number of columns, and no field contains commas", you could pre-process the file to (1) remove all newlines (2) process the file again and separate it into lines of N columns each by counting commas (3) process the file line by line and deal with double quotes inside fields. But you need to tell us what can be guaranteed about this file.

Comment: Without any guarantees, no one can determine whether this input contains one or two lines of data, four or three fields: `"a", "b",\n"c", "d"`. If one field can contain double quotes, commas and newlines, then `b",\n"c` is one field, and the input contains one line of data, with three fields. It could even be one line of data, with one field. We need to know  what is guaranteed about the data, otherwise the problem may not have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

stop using `toMap` function in `zippedWithIndex.map(cur => (cur._2,cur._1)).toMap`. That is the reason for your *GC overhead limit exceeded* error. process the entire file lazily for instance as shown below

```
val lines = for {
    (line,index) <- Source.fromFile("output.txt").getLines.zipWithIndex
} yield (line -> index)

def cleaningFunction(currentLine: String, nextLine: String): String = {
   //hypothetical cleaning function
}

val result =  lines.toSeq zip lines.toSeq.tail // stream based sequence to access before/after lines

result.map((x,y) => cleaningFunction(x,y))
```

lines would now have the cleaned content of your file which can be used later.